# Ignore excel vba errors during read cell values from C# through COM interop

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop, vba

I am running VBA macros from C# which can yield errors. These errors are characterized by a pop-up prompting for debugging, interrupting the application and requiring user input. I need these macros and they cannot be disabled.

How I can ignore these errors or close dialogs automatically?

Comment: OP, have you found a solution there ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample spreadsheet that throws errors and the code you are using to read the values?

Comment: I don't think that'll help. Assume, for example, calling a simple macro Test1, with a single instruction, passing a double to a function expecting a string. That would yield a type mismatch error at runtime, yielding the aforementioned pop-up interrupting execution.

Answer (score 1):

Ör in the most simplest easiest way. Include `on error resume next` in your macros,so that the macro wont stop at errors.

Comment: Indeed :) but outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the visual basic editor (which shows when a error occurs) before attempting to open the file, change the Excel.VBE.MainWindow.Visible to false. Be aware that if the debugger is not shown, you will have to catch an exception in your code, so, envelope your code with an try catch.

If macros are not needed and can be ignored, use the msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable to disable them completely.

```
using InteropExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

var Excel = new InteropExcel.Application ();

// Excel window will NOT popup if macro errors are found but
// exceptions might be raised when you execute the broken
// macro.
Excel.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = false;

// Uncomment to disable macros completely.
// Excel.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;

// I used this snippet to open a file with a broken macro.
var MyWorkbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open (@"YourFilePath");
var FirstWorksheet = (InteropExcel.Worksheet)MyWorkbook.Worksheets ["Plan1"];
var MyCell = ((InteropExcel.Range)FirstWorksheet.Cells [1,1]);
var CellValue = (Int32)MyCell.Value;
```

Comment: I'm afraid macros cannot be ignored here.

Comment: I updated my answer with the solution to hide macro errors.

Comment: Excel.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = false; has no effect I'm afraid

Comment: Post an example of how you are doing the task because I made a macro enable excel file, wrote a bugged macro that ran when I open the file and it did prevent the debugger from appearing.

Comment: workbook events were disabled most likely and the macro simply may  not have run. Try to call explicitly the macro as described in the post from your C# code, and you'll see.